# Get the first and last shippment and arrive date for all users

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have table for shipping Company.

The columns are (NationalID, shipmentdate, arraivaldate ..)

The question is:
how can I get the **first shippment date and arrival date** and **last shippment date and arrival date** for each user

This is THE sample data:

| NationalID | shippmetdate | arrivalDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 115 | 2020-10-08 | 2021-03-18 |
| 115 | 2023-02-08 | 1990-01-01 |
| 115 | 2021-08-11 | 2021-08-20 |

I use this QUERY but it's not working

```
select NationalID,
    min(shippmetdate) as first_shippment,
    min(arrivalDate) as arrival_first,
    max(shippmetdate) as last_shippment,
    max(arrivalDate)as arrival_last
from (
    select NationalID, shippmetdate, arrivalDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by NationalID order by shippmetdate) as seq1, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by NationalID order by arrivalDate) as seq2 
    from shippment
) t 
group by NationalID
```

The output is:

| NationalID | first_shippment | arrival_first | last_shippment | arrival_last |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 115 | 2020-10-08 | 1990-01-01 | 2023-02-08 | 2021-08-20 |

**BUT I want the output like**

| NationalID | first_shippment | arrival_first | last_shippment | arrival_last |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 115 | 2020-10-08 | 2021-03-18 | 2023-02-08 | 1990-01-01 |

**Actually I want get the row of the first_shippment then I will return the arrival date for same row**

I try to use max and min for the date but the output is not matching.

Comment: Just want to comment that you made a great job creating a new question and give much better details!

Comment: "for each user" define what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the first and last shipment date with just `min` and `max`.

As for the corresponding arrival dates, you are on the right track by enumerating the records of each user, then aggregating. You would need to use *conditional aggregation* in the outer query; also, the sequences should be adapted: both should `order by` the shipment date, but in different directions.

So:

```
select NationalID,
    min(shipmentDate) as firstShipmentDate,
    max(case when seq1 = 1 then arrivalDate  end) as firstShipmentArrivalDate,
    max(shipmentDate) as lastShipmentDate,
    max(case when seq2 = 1 then arrivalDate  end) as lastShipmentArrivalDate
from (
    select s.*,
        row_number() over (partition by NationalID order by shipmentDate     ) as seq1, 
        row_number() over (partition by NationalID order by shipmentDate desc) as seq2 
    from shipment s
) s
group by NationalID
```

| NationalID | firstShipmentDate | firstShipmentArrivalDate | lastShipmentDate | lastShipmentArrivalDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 115 | 2020-10-08 | 2021-03-18 | 2023-02-08 | 1990-01-01 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9tvH6lHP)

Comment: Two row-numbers requires an extra sort. Instead do `lead(1) over (partition by NationalID order by shipmentDate) as seq2` and check it for `null`, to keep the same sort order

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the MIN and MAX functions directly on shippmetdate and arrivalDate, you can use a subquery to get the corresponding arrivalDate for the first and last shipments.

```
SELECT
  NationalID,
  first_shipment,
  (SELECT arrivalDate FROM shippment WHERE NationalID = t.NationalID AND shippmetdate = t.first_shipment) AS arrival_first,
  last_shipment,
  (SELECT arrivalDate FROM shippment WHERE NationalID = t.NationalID AND shippmetdate = t.last_shipment) AS arrival_last
FROM (
  SELECT
    NationalID,
    MIN(shippmetdate) AS first_shipment,
    MAX(shippmetdate) AS last_shipment
  FROM shippment
  GROUP BY NationalID
) t;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9c568/2

Answer (score 0):

you could also use the Join statement as follows:

```sql
SELECT first_.NationalID, first_.first_shippment, first_.first_arrivalDate, last_.last_shippment, last_.last_arrivalDate
FROM
    (SELECT NationalID, arrivalDate AS first_arrivalDate, MIN(shippmetdate) AS first_shippment
    FROM shippment
    GROUP BY NationalID) AS first_
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT NationalID, arrivalDate AS last_arrivalDate, MAX(shippmetdate) AS last_shippment
    FROM shippment
    GROUP BY NationalID) AS last_
ON (first_.NationalID = last_.NationalID);
```

and with this get the following:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @GMB is the best so far, but it requires an extra sort, because of the opposing row-numbers.

**It is possible to do this with a single windowing order, by using `LEAD`.**

```sql
select
  s.NationalID,
  min(s.shipmentDate) as firstShipmentDate,
  max(case when seq = 1 then s.arrivalDate end) as firstShipmentArrivalDate,
  max(s.shipmentDate) as lastShipmentDate,
  max(case when s.hasNextRow is null then s.arrivalDate end) as lastShipmentArrivalDate
from (
    select s.*,
        row_number() over (partition by s.NationalID order by s.shipmentDate) as seq, 
        lead(1) over (partition by s.NationalID order by s.shipmentDate) as hasNextRow
    from shipment s
) s
group by
  s.NationalID
```

If the table has an index `(NationalID, shipmentDate) INCLUDE (arrivalDate)` then no sorts are required at all with this solution.